# Android - Edit Text ... Input from keyboard not accepted

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application, in an activity i have 4 edit Text fields and a button. Only After entering data for all 4 edit text fields, data will be submitted. If one is empty, i am showing an alert dialog stating my custom error message. Now in the activity if i click on edit text and press any key on keyboard, the text is not appened to edit text.

If you have faced a similar issue please do let me know.enter code here

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_field"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TextView01"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&apos;."
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:typeface="sans" >
    </EditText>
```

In .java File

in Oncreate Method

```
first_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_field);

        InputFilter[] filter = new InputFilter[1];
        filter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(24);
        first_field.setFilters(filter);
```

in Onclick event for the button

```
 NumberKeyListener keyListener1 = new NumberKeyListener() {

                public int getInputType() {
                return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
                }

                @Override
                protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
                return new char[] { '.','‘' };
                }
            };
            first_field.setKeyListener(keyListener1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented this part of the code in Onclick method and it worked fine.

```
     NumberKeyListener keyListener1 = new NumberKeyListener() {
          public int getInputType() {
             return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT; 
        }
          @Override
         protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
         return new char[] { '.','‘' };
         }
     };
     first_field.setKeyListener(keyListener1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to specify `android:editable` in your xml definition.
According to the setFilters method it "Sets the list of input filters that will be used if the buffer is Editable."

Answer (score 0):

editText in change u pot inputtext = true

Comment: I cant understand what you are saying